# Powershell drive map with authentication?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to make a script in powershell (if you have suggestions for another tool to make this with please advise) that would map network drives for userA to map their own drives temporarily while userB is still logged in.

I tried to use both the New-PSDrive method, as well as the MapNetworkDrive method.

They both throw this error:

```
"Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again"
```

After I saw this, I tried disconnecting all drives associated with the server before connecting the desired share via:

```
net use * /d /y
net use \\server\ipc$
net use \\server\ipc$ /d /y
```

(thanks @jessehouwing !)

The same error still occurs.

If you want to check my connection code I have it below:

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive($drLetter, $share, $false, $user, $pass)
```

and

```
New-PSDrive -Name $drLetter -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $share -Credential $user -Persist
```

Comment: Normally one would run `net use` to see which shares are still connected (don't forget the `IPC$` share), and use `net use \\server\share /delete` to remove them. Just disconnecting the shared drives, doesn't remove their connection cache from the network manager.

Comment: @jessehouwing Could you explain what IPC$ is, as well as the significance of the connection cache? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: When connecting to a server the credentials are cached on the client. When you just browse to a server to see what services it advertises (printers, shares etc), a connection is made to the IPC$ share. Only when all of these connections are deleted, can you establish a connection using a different account.

Comment: See also: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb1cfb9f-5b06-405c-a6ff-0a324102fd25/question-about-the-ipc-share?forum=winserversecurity

Comment: @jessehouwing It is still not working, but `net use * /d /y` is definitely easier than my foreach! Thanks for the knowledge of `ipc$` and help!

Comment: Which user's context is performing the disconnects?  I think you will have trouble having one user disconnect another user's drive mappings.  I'm continually frustrated that Administrator cannot use my regular user's mounted drives (under Win7Pro, at least), so I suspect similar issues with disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are not allowed to have multiple connection to the same resource with *different* credentials. I am going to Assume you don't just have a temporary connection to this resource defined by `server`.

What I always to in situations like this is use the IP address of the host. so...

```
net use \\10.10.10.10\ipc$
```

I am going to try and find the articles that discuss what is occurring here but in short this will allow the separate connections.